# r replace part of a string with lookup

Tags: r, regex, vector, replace

I have two dataframes:

DF1: mapping - two columns

```
code | value
SDR111X | 10
DER333F | 15
```

DF2: data - one column (I added two more columns in my script - below)

```
string
AA.SDR111X AS SDR111X
AB.SDR111X AS SDR111X
DD.YRE999C AS YRE999C
```

The aim is to iterate through DF1, for each row, take a look in DF2 and replace the SECOND match of CODE with the VALUE, the result I would expect:

```
string
AA.SDR111X AS 10
AB.SDR111X AS 10
DD.YRE999C AS YRE999C
```

At this point I have started trying to work out how do the replacement part of the requirement.

I will work on the iteration part of the code afterwards!

I have tried the following with no success - the code runs OK, but no values are changed:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data
data <- data %>%
  mutate(lhs = substr(X__1, 1, 14)) %>%
  mutate(rhs = substr(X__1, 15, 200))

pattern <- "SDR111X"
replacement <- "10"

str_replace_all(data$rhs, pattern, replacement)
```

The same thing happens here:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data
data <- data %>%
  mutate(lhs = substr(X__1, 1, 14)) %>%
  mutate(rhs = substr(X__1, 15, 200))

data <- data %>%
  mutate(rhs1 = replace(rhs, rhs=="SDR111X", 10))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please provide data using `dput()` function (`|` in `DF1` is misleading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `fuzzyjoin` package to join both data frames before performing replacement can suit the problem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

DF2 %>% regex_left_join(DF1, by = c("string" = "code")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(string = gsub(paste(code,"$",sep=""), value, string)) %>%
  select(string)

# # A tibble: 3 x 1
#        string               
#        <chr>                
# 1 AA.SDR111X AS 10     
# 2 AB.SDR111X AS 10     
# 3 DD.YRE999C AS YRE999C
```

**Data:**

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = 
"code  value
SDR111X  10
DER333F  15",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


DF2 <- read.table(text = 
"string
'AA.SDR111X AS SDR111X'
'AB.SDR111X AS SDR111X'
'DD.YRE999C AS YRE999C'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution using the tidyverse world.

```
df1<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="code  value
SDR111X  10
DER333F  15")
df2<-data.frame(string= c('AA.SDR111X AS SDR111X', 'AB.SDR111X AS SDR111X', 'DD.YRE999C AS YRE999C' ))


library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#find what to match (last word in the string)
df2$match<-str_extract(df2$string, "\\w+$")
#make the join using the match and code columns
df2<-left_join(df2, df1, by=c("match"="code"))
#fill in the NA with the original word in the string
df2$value[is.na(df2$value)]<-df2$match[is.na(df2$value)]

#final answer
answer<-data.frame(string=str_replace(df2$string, "\\w+$", df2$value))
```